# Decoding JSON into a non-alias type

Tags: json, elm

I'm trying to decode directly or indirectly recursive types in Elm, which requires that at least one of them is defined as a "proper", non-alias, type.  I'm using `Json.Decode.Pipeline`.  Here's how I would do it with an `alias`, which obviously doesn't work:

```
import Json.Decode as Jdec
import Json.Decode.Pipeline as Jpipe

type alias List =
    { next : Maybe List
    , item : Float
    }

list : Jdec.Decoder List
list =
    Jpipe.decode List
        |> Jpipe.optional "next" (Jdec.nullable list) Nothing
        |> Jpipe.required "item" Jdec.float
```

How do I make the decoding function work if `List` is properly defined as

```
type List = List
    { next : Maybe List
    , item : Float
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define your recursive type as you suggest:

```
type List = List
    { next : Maybe List
    , item : Float
    }
```

then you still need to overcome two obstacles in writing your decoder.

The first is that List is no longer the name of a type alias, and therefore, is no longer a function of two arguments that creates a list. Instead, List is a constructor, taking in one argument of type `{next : Maybe List, item : Float}`.

The second is that you will need to refer to `list`, the decoder, in the definition of `list`, which is flagged by the compiler as "bad recursion."

The solution to the first problem is to create your own list-making function: `(\next item -> List {next=next, item=item})`. The solution to the second problem is to use `Json.Decode.lazy`, which lets you use a decoder-returning closure in the place of a decoder:

```
list : Jdec.Decoder List
list =
    Jdec.map2 (\next item -> List {next=next, item=item})
          (Jdec.field "next" (Jdec.lazy (\_ -> Jdec.nullable list)))
          (Jdec.field "item" Jdec.float)
```